# Grouping in Entity Framework MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

Hi all i've currently got a list of telephone numbers being output using:-

Controller:-

```
public ActionResult ViewSubRange(int id)
{
    IEnumerable<Number> numbers = context.Numbers.Where(m => m.RangeID == id).ToList();

    return View("SubRange", numbers);
}
```

View:-

```
@model IEnumerable<TelephoneNumberManagement.Models.Number>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr> 
        <td>@item.Number1</td>
        <td>@item.Status.StatusName</td>
    </tr> 

}

</table>
```

This is fine, however i've noticed that we can have a lot of numbers being output. I was wondering if its possible to group the numbers, so for example by Customer. So what i want to achieve is something like:-

> 01132210000-01132210999 CUSTOMER A
>
> 01132211000-01132211009 CUSTOMER B
>
> 01132211010-01132211029 CUSTOMER C

Comment: I think you'd need to write logic to assemble the groups yourself - there's LINQ to group by customer but I can't think of anything to turn a set of numbers into a string describing the range they cover (barring simple min / max, ignoring whether the range is covered or not)

Comment: Just like the good link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746 Hereyou can find good examples of linq using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a new view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public string Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

and then group by customer name:

```
public ActionResult ViewSubRange(int id) 
{
    var numbers = context.Numbers
        .Where(m => m.RangeID == id)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Status.StatusName)
        .Select(x => new MyViewModel
        {
            StatusName = x.Key,

            // TODO: could change the format if you will or
            // select the min and max or whatever you need
            Numbers = string.Join("-", x.Select(n => n.Number1)) 
        })
        .ToList();
    return View(numbers);
}
```

and finally in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr> 
            <td>@item.Numbers</td>
            <td>@item.StatusName</td>
        </tr> 
    }
</table>
```